# Can I put a 2 pin switch on breadboard busses?

Tags: power-supply, breadboard, jumper

I want to run a 12V battery into the breadboard busses, but they are 12 gauge wire so I want to use 2 pin screw terminals. The battery will power another device which also has 12 gauge wire so I'll use another screw terminal. Can I put a 2 pin push button switch on the positive and negative busses? Can my other screw terminal be on the busses or does it need to go somewhere else? Would a 4 pin switch be better with jumper wires?

Comment: First ask yourself if you should be trying to run whatever current is going through your 12 gauge wire through breadboard busses which are optimistically rated for 1 amp.

Comment: Please draw a schematic so we can understand what you are trying to do. DO NOT run anything requiring #12 wire through a plastic breadboard!

Comment: @vir I don't see current being a problem, as i'm already an identical battery on the other side for a different device. I really just don't know where to place a switch to simply cut the battery signal to the actuator

Comment: @PeterBennet I need the battery connected to the bus strips, then a switch to turn the power on and off. I don't know where to put the switch on the breadboard and I don't know where to place the terminal for the output

Comment: What current does the device you want to supply power to require?  I would expect something using #12 wire to use 10 amps or more - much more than you should try to put through a breadboard, and much more than any switch that would plug into a breadboard could safely handle.

Comment: @PeterBennett it looks like it requires a dedicated 25 to 40 amp circuit. I guess I'm looking at an alternative method now. Thank you for your help

Comment: Yikes!!  That definitely requires heavy duty wiring and a switch rated to handle the current.